# Solar Calculation and Projection in ArcGIS Pro on all buildings?

Tags: arcgis-pro, solar-radiation

I am using this example to my project:

http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/solar-radiation-maps/get-started/explore-solar-radiation/

I have a layer of 3D Buildings as shown in the image:

When I applied the Calculation of the Solar Radiation on these Buildings Roofs, I found that the calculation is shown ONLY on the right 3d Building, whereas the middle and the left buildings are not calculated. Like this image:

[image]

Then, I suggested to myself to select these two buildings ONLY  and process the calculation of solar radiation to detect where is the problem. I did, but the result was not shown. Then I zoomed to the resulted layer, and found that these two 3D buildings are on Canada map rather being in Saudi.

I really surprising why this happened!

All of the 3D Buildings are in one layer as I mentioned earlier.

Is there any suggestion or solution why this problem occur in my work?

Comment: The resulted layer of these two buildings which I mentioned that they are on top on Canada map, can be seen from this link :   https://geonet.esri.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-676442-344702/ARCGIS29032017.png